# Проверка на пустые текстбоксы и маскедтекстбоксы через try catch в С++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, try-catch

Есть вот такой код. Мне нужно чтобы все `if else` были запиханы в `try catch`.

```
if (count_Upr_PP == 0) {
    if (!(maskedTextBox1->MaskFull) || !(maskedTextBox2->MaskFull)) {
        MessageBox::Show("Введите время тренировки!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
    }
    else if (textBox1->Text == "" || !(maskedTextBox3->MaskFull)) {
        MessageBox::Show("Необходимые поля не заполнены!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
    }
    else {
        SystemTime = Convert::ToDateTime(DateTime::Now);
        betweentime = TimeTrainBegin - SystemTime;
        TimeTrainBegin = Convert::ToDateTime(maskedTextBox1->Text);
        TimeTrainEnd = Convert::ToDateTime(maskedTextBox2->Text);
        if (TimeTrainEnd < TimeTrainBegin) {
            MessageBox::Show("Время введено некорректно!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
        }
        else if (TimeTrainBegin == TimeTrainEnd) {
            MessageBox::Show("Время начала и конца тренировки не могут быть равны!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
        }
        else {
            File::Delete(Amount);
            StreamWriter^ Training = gcnew StreamWriter(DayWeek, false);
            Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox1->Text);
            Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox2->Text);
            Training->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
            Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox3->Text);
            Training->Close();
            button1->Enabled = false;
            button2->Enabled = false;
            button3->Enabled = true;
            button4->Enabled = false;
            maskedTextBox1->Enabled = false;
            maskedTextBox2->Enabled = false;
            maskedTextBox3->Enabled = false;
            textBox1->Enabled = false;
            timer1->Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
else if (count_Upr_PP != 0) {
    if (!(maskedTextBox1->MaskFull) || !(maskedTextBox2->MaskFull)) {
       MessageBox::Show("Введите время тренировки!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
    }
    else if (textBox1->Text == "" || !(maskedTextBox3->MaskFull)) {
         MessageBox::Show("Необходимые поля не заполнены!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
    }
    else {
        SystemTime = Convert::ToDateTime(DateTime::Now);
        betweentime = TimeTrainBegin - SystemTime;
        TimeTrainBegin = Convert::ToDateTime(maskedTextBox1->Text);
        TimeTrainEnd = Convert::ToDateTime(maskedTextBox2->Text);
        if (TimeTrainEnd < TimeTrainBegin) {
                MessageBox::Show("Время введено некорректно!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
        }
        else if (TimeTrainBegin == TimeTrainEnd) {
                MessageBox::Show("Время начала и конца тренировки не могут быть равны!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
        }
        else {
            for each (TextBox^ Lupr in LUprPP) {
                if (Lupr->Text == "") {
                    MessageBox::Show("Не все поля 'Упражнение' заполнены!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    flag_upr = true;
                }
            }
            for each (MaskedTextBox^ Lpp in Lpp) {
                if (!(Lpp->MaskFull)) {
                    MessageBox::Show("Не все поля 'Подходов/повторений' заполнены!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    flag_pp = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag_pp == true && flag_upr == true) {
             StreamWriter^ Training = gcnew StreamWriter(DayWeek, false);
             Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox1->Text);
             Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox2->Text);
             Training->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
             Training->WriteLine(maskedTextBox3->Text);
             for each (TextBox^ Lupr in LUprPP) {
                 Training->WriteLine(Lupr->Text);
                 Lupr->Enabled = false;
             }
             for each (MaskedTextBox^ Lpp in Lpp) {
                 Training->WriteLine(Lpp->Text);
                 Lpp->Enabled = false;
             }
             Training->Close();
             count_Upr_PP = LUprPP->Count;
             StreamWriter^ Amount_Upr_PP = gcnew StreamWriter(Amount, false);
             Amount_Upr_PP->WriteLine(count_Upr_PP);
             Amount_Upr_PP->Close();
             button1->Enabled = false;
             button2->Enabled = false;
             button3->Enabled = true;
             button4->Enabled = false;
             maskedTextBox1->Enabled = false;
             maskedTextBox2->Enabled = false;
             maskedTextBox3->Enabled = false;
             textBox1->Enabled = false;
             button6->Enabled = false;
             timer1->Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Я пытался запихать весь этот код в `try`, а потом в `catch(...){сообщение_об_ошибке}`, но код работал неправильно (Выдавало сообщение об ошибке из `catch` всегда. Но вообще мне надо чтобы в `catch` были прописаны разные сообщения об ошибке, но как это сделать? Я так понял в `catch` надо передавать тип исключения, а что за тип у `maskedTextBox1->MaskFull`, например, я не знаю.